# CURL Post looping

Tags: php, post, file-upload, curl

I am running a script which uploads a file to remote form

```
  //submit form
  $form_data = array("file_upload" => "@file.xml;type=text/xml","otherkey" => "overvalue");
  $ch = curl_init();
  $form_url = 'http://www.domain.com/form.php';
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $form_url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $form_data);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);      
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
  $postResult = curl_exec($ch);
  echo $postResult;
```

The file is being uploaded perfectly, however on the remote server, after file upload and processing the page is reloaded (form.php), however the CURL post simply begins again.

I am guessing this is due to the POST data still being present? how can I do this so that the file is uploaded once, processed and then completed? I have set FOLLOWLOCATION = 0 but with no luck

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you know it begins again? If you infer it from your echo, it is echoed twice as you write this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0); //echoes result at init
```

instead of this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //returns only result, not echoing
```

Comment: CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.

Comment: That's what I meant, in case of false or 0, it outputs response and returns true if succeed. Now I think however buzzmonkey means something else, I didn't understand the explanation of a problem.

Comment: Many thanks to n-dru, by returning the data and not echoing - script isn't lopping. Using  $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); also confirms that the file upload was successful . thanks guys!